# How can I avoid some suggestions in vscode? ("abc log")

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When I type "log" in vscode, I get a useless suggestion:

[image]

Commiting this suggestion does nothing. I always have to select the second suggestion, "log to console". This occurs in javascript code, in typescript code not.

I found the setting

```
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false  // does not work
```

but setting this to false does not change this.

Where does this useless suggestion come from and how can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the setting you're looking for is:

`"editor.suggest.showWords": false`

You can find a full list of intellisense settings explained here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

And the list of completions can be found here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions

hope this helped.